Evaluating $\int_0^{2R}y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy$
I was calculating the work done along a path when I encountered this integral $$\int_0^{2R}y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy$$
I found one method to solve this. First do $2R-y=a$ then do $2R-a=w^2$ then do $w=\sqrt{2R}\sin u$ and then simplify and separate the terms and solve the integral of $\sin^6 u$ and $\sin^8 u$.
But this method is very lengthy. I want to know if these is some easy or less lengthier method to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I would have done $y=R+z$, $z=Rt$, $t=\cos\theta$ and got a couple of $\sin^k $ integrals of lower degree that yours. Not much shorter but seems to me "what we always do" [Complete square, scale, trig].

With $y = 2Rx$, it reduces to a beta integral: $$
(2R)^4 \int_0^1 {x^2 \sqrt {x - x^2 } {\rm d}x}  = (2R)^4 \int_0^1 {x^{5/2} (1 - x)^{1/2} {\rm d}x}
$$

@Gary dammit...you're a genius

Suggestion:
You may work out the following reduction formula
$$ \int_0^{2R}y^n\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy =I_n = \frac{(2n+1)R}{n+2}I_{n-1}
$$
to run down the integral
$$\int_0^{2R}y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy =I_2 = \frac{5R}{4} I_1
= \frac{5R^2}{4} I_0= \frac{5\pi R^4}{8}
$$

By the method of completing squares, we have
$$
\int_0^{2 R} y^2 \sqrt{2 R y-y^2} d y=\int_0^{2 R} y^2 \sqrt{R^2-(R-y)^2} d y
$$
Let $R-y=R\cos \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & \int_0^\pi R^2(1-\cos \theta)^2 R^2 \sin ^2 \theta d \theta \\
= & R^4 \int_0^\pi\left(\sin ^2 \theta-2 \cos \theta \sin ^2 \theta+\cos ^2 \theta \sin ^2 \theta\right) d \theta \\
= & R^4\left[\int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} d \theta-2 \int_0^\pi \sin ^2 \theta d(\sin \theta)\quad+\frac{1}{4} \int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos 4 \theta}{2} d \theta\right] \\
= & R^4\left[\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}-\frac{2 \sin ^3 \theta}{3}+\frac{1}{8}\left(\theta-\frac{\sin 4 \theta}{4}\right)\right]_0^\pi \\
= &\frac{5 \pi}{8}R^4
\end{aligned}
$$



The following menthod (maybe not a better method for OP's integral) is to deal with the integral of the following type:
$$\int P_n(y)\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y+\gamma}\ dy,$$
which can be writen as
$$\int P_n(y)\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y+\gamma}\ dy
=Q_{n+1}(y)\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y+\gamma}+\lambda\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y+\gamma}},$$
where $P_n(y),Q_{n+1}(y)$ are polynomials of degree $n$ and $n+1$, $\lambda$ is constant.


The integral $$\int y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}\ dy$$
can be writen as
$$\int y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}\ dy=P(y)\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}+\lambda\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}},\tag{*}$$
where $P(y)$ is a polynomial and $\lambda$ is constant.
Differentiate $(*)$, we can get
$$y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}=P'(y)\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}+P(y)\frac{a-y}{\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}}
+\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}}.$$
Multiply $\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}$ both sides, we can get
$$y^2(2Ry-y^2)=P'(y)(2Ry-y^2)+P(y)(a-y)+\lambda.$$
From this we can get the degree of $P(y)$ is $3$.
Suppose $P(y)=ay^3+by^2+cy+d$,then
$$y^2(2Ry-y^2)=(3ay^2+2by+c)(2Ry-y^2)+(ay^3+by^2+cy+d)(a-y)+\lambda.$$
Byy computation, we get
$$a=\frac14,\quad b=\frac{-R}{12},\quad c=\frac{-5R^2}{24},\quad d=\frac{-5R^3}{8},\quad \lambda=\frac{5R^4}{8}.$$
Hence,
$$\int y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}\ dy
=\left(\frac14y^3-\frac{R}{12}y^2-\frac{5R^2}{24}y
-\frac{5R^3}{8}\right)\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}
+\frac{5R^4}{8}\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}},$$
with
$$\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}}
=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{R^2-(y-R)^2}}
=\arcsin\frac{y-R}{R}+C.$$
So
$$\int_0^{2R}y^2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy
=\frac{5R^4}{8}\arcsin\frac{y-R}{R}\Bigg|_0^{2R}
=\frac{5\pi R^4}{8}$$
